# Construct object from vector using move

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move, stdvector

I have a code like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(std::vector &vec):
        v(vec)
    {}
    MyClass(??);

private:
    std::vector v;
};
```

I would like to construct my class like this `MyClass(std::move(some_vector))`
**How can I achieve that?**

I can change 4 line to `v(std::move(vec))` but this is hidden move, due to dangerous.

EDIT:
Example

```
int main {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2}
    MyClass myobj(v); // this should be disallowed
    //MyClass myobj(std::move(v)) //this should be the only way
    //here v is empty
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable only the move constructor

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(std::vector &&vec):
        v(std::move(vec))
    {}
    MyClass() = delete; //prevent default constructor if you wish
private:
    std::vector v;
};
```

Comment: It looks nice. Bu I want to ensure that only `MyClass(std::move(my_vector))` is allowed. Your code allow to empty vector (my_vector) in-explicitly. If i will modify this code in 5 year I will not remember that vector was moved.

Comment: @S.R I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @S.R It doesn't allow empty vectors. It allows default constructors. Is that what you mean? I added that.

Comment: Go beyond this class. You have a code in main(). And you see `MyClass(my_vector)`. Are you expecting that in the next line `my_vector` is empty? If it is only possible I want to force using  `MyClass(std::move(my_vector))`

Comment: @S.R What does empty mean? 0 elements? You can't ensure that's the case at compile-time. Please describe in the question in detail what is it that you want to prevent. I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @S.R - Why don't you actually post a [mcve] with a `main` function rather than describe it ambiguously? I'm sure our Physicist friend will happily help you if you clarify yourself properly.

Comment: It looks like CoryKramer answer is what I want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484711/construct-object-from-vector-using-move#comment77930726_45484791. This ensure that I will never end up with empty vector if I don't use move.

Comment: It took my a long time to understand you. I changed accepted answer. Your is better!

Answer (score 4):

I would just accept a `std::vector` by value then `std::move` it internally

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(std::vector vec):
        v(std::move(vec))
    {}

private:
    std::vector v;
};
```

Comment: I want to save space. The vector I will receive will be never used anymore. So I want to allow create my class just by  std::move statemant.

Comment: You still can, `MyClass(std::move(my_vector))` will work using this constructor and no copies will be made

Answer (score 0):

You could do that:

```
struct MyClass {
    // rvalue only
    MyClass(std::vector&& vec):
        v(std::move(vec))
    {}

    // lvalue
    MyClass(const std::vector&) = delete;

private:
    std::vector v;
};
```

Any attempt to call the lvalue version will fail, calling the deleted overload.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you how to create a class that will give
you the option to initilize the class with or without
the vector with other arguments present and/or not present.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::to_string;

class Parse
{
private:
    string         m_str;
    vector<string> m_vec;
public:
    // Constructor 1/4 with all defaults
    Parse(){ 
        cout << "\ncreating class with all default values\n";
        m_str = "";
        m_vec.push_back("");    
    }

    // Constructor 2/4 with all cases used
    Parse  (string         &tmp_str,
            vector<string> tmp_vec):

            m_str          (tmp_str),
            m_vec          (tmp_vec)
    {
        cout << "Your vector contains " + to_string(m_str.size()) + " arguments\n";
    }

    // Constructor 3/4 with other contents given but not vector
    Parse  (string         &tmp_str): 
            m_str          (tmp_str)
    {
        m_vec.push_back("");
    }
    // Constructor 4/4 with only Vector given but not other contents
    Parse  (vector<string>   tmp_vec):
            m_vec           (tmp_vec)
    {
        m_str = "";
    }

    string get_str_var(){return m_str;}

    void classed_print_vector_strings()
    {
        for (string i : m_vec){ cout << i << " \n";}
    }

};



// rm ./class_vector; g++ class_vector.cpp -o class_vector -std=c++17; ./class_vector arg1 arg2 arg3

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // turn **argv to a vector
    vector<string> args(argv, argv + argc);
    // iterate from argv through argv+argc

    // initialize with default arguments.
    Parse tracker1;
    // initalize with all used arguments
    Parse tracker2(args[0], args);
    // initalize with only the vector
    Parse tracker3(args);
    // initalzie without the vector, but with another arg
    Parse tracker4(args[0]);

    cout << "\nTracker 1 ---------------------\n";
    tracker1.classed_print_vector_strings();
    cout << "\nTracker 2 ---------------------\n";
    tracker2.classed_print_vector_strings();
    cout << "\nTracker 3 ---------------------\n";
    tracker3.classed_print_vector_strings();
    cout << "\nTracker 4 ---------------------\n";
    tracker4.classed_print_vector_strings();


    return 0;
}
```

```
rm ./class_vector; g++ class_vector.cpp -o class_vector -std=c++17; ./class_vector arg1 arg2 arg3
```